# Trying to implement javascript timer in online test website

Tags: javascript, php, timer

Hi guys i am trying to implement java-script timer in my online test project, have done all the coding with the help of tutorial because i don't know java-script. The timer gets time duration from the database.
I am facing two problems, The timer gets reset to initial value when i move to next question via a submit button. Also i want to set that when timer ends and reaches 00:00:00, (An alert box should be displayed) & it should redirect to 'testfinish.php' on pressing OK. I have done below coding so far :-

**on teststart.php**

```
<?php
$end='00:00:00';
$ftc=mysqli_query($connection,"select test_dur from test_detail where test_name='$tstnm1';");
$str=mysqli_fetch_array($ftc);
$dur=$str["test_dur"];
$_SESSION["dur"]=$dur;
$_SESSION["sttime"]=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$etime=$etime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+'.$_SESSION["dur"].'minutes', strtotime($_SESSION["sttime"])));
$_SESSION["etime"]=$etime;
if($etime==$end)
{
header('location:testfinish.php');
}
}
?>
```

**////Some Javascript on same page**

```
<div id="response"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function()
{
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","response.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
},1000);
</script>
```

**response.php**

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';
$tstnm2=htmlentities($_SESSION['tstnm']);
$dur="";
$end='00:00:00';
$ftc=mysqli_query($connection,"select test_dur from test_detail where test_name='$tstnm2';");
$str=mysqli_fetch_array($ftc);
$dur=$str["test_dur"];

$_SESSION["dur"]=$dur;
$_SESSION["sttime"]=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$etime=$etime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+'.$_SESSION["dur"].'minutes', strtotime($_SESSION["sttime"])));
$_SESSION["etime"]=$etime;

if($etime==$end)
{
    header('location:testfinish.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little difficult to read, but you may consider starting a new timer on every page using the value of the previous timer. You may also find it easier to implement the timer in JavaScript. Here is one I was working on last night:

http://codepen.io/WallyNally/pen/pPJVVY

```
timer = document.getElementById('time');
time = 120;

timer.innerHTML = "before";

function tick(t) {
  $i = t - .1;
  time = $i;
  timer.innerHTML = Math.ceil(time);
}
stopTime = setInterval(function() {
      if (time > -.1) {
      tick(time);
      } else {
        clearInterval(stopTime);
      }
    }, 100);
```

When the user presses submit, let PHP collect the value of `<input type="hidden" id="time" name="time" value="{time}" />`. You can have a separate, visible element to show the user the countdown.

```
    <?php $_SESSION['hold_time'] = $_POST['time']?> 

    Then on the next page, set the timer to that saved value. 

    <script>
    timekeeper = document.getElementById('time');
    clock = document.getElementById('show-time');

    //Then use the function above with (clock).

    timekeeper.value = <?php echo $_SESSION['time']; ?>
    </script>
```

The idea you have for stopping at 0 seems to be on the right track.

Comment: `code` <input type="hidden" id="time" name="time" value="{time}">